# Should reflection be part of design?

Tags: c#, data, real-time, reflection

I'm currently designing a somewhat large program that will involve the simulation of math/physics models and collection of data (I have not implemented any code yet). One of the main problems I'm facing is how to pass data around easily without having to have multiple copies of data (that may potentially be outdated and redundant).

Initially I was thinking of having the model objects each implement a function that returns a data structure containing copies of their data, then collecting all those data structures together and passing that around. This would involve a lot of copying however, and the data wouldn't be mapped to the actual object anymore. (The data structure idea I had would involve using a trie so that the data is nice and hierarchical and lookups can be done easily by string)

So now I was thinking that instead of designing the program to use a data structure to pass data around, the program would simply pass the model, and then data can be extracted with reflection. This would pretty much avoid any redundancy and the data passed will always be up to date.

The problem is that I also need this program to be fast (it has soft realtime constraints), and I'm not sure about the performance impact of reflection. And reflection does seem kinda ugly. But at the same time, people say it's never a good idea to optimize early, so I'm on the fence here.

So should I design the program to use reflection, and if so, how liberally? Or should I try to avoid reflection as much as I can during design?

Comment: What more can you do with reflection that you couldn't with interfaces in your scenario?

Comment: Can you expand upon your thoughts about using reflection and provide a simple example of what you would do?

Comment: It doesn't exactly sound like "reflection" is the problem. Correct me if I'm way off-base, but the underlying problem is that the data can change after it is calculated. If you calculate it and give it away in a data structure it could become stale, if you recalculate it from the model every time you need it, it will be fresh(er), but you may be burning too much time doing repetitive calculations. I would not choose either path until I built some test cases with typical algorithms to see if the calc time is significant and then estimate how many times you could potentially have to call it.

Comment: Mike is pretty spot-on on what I'm facing here. The reason why the data can become old is because sometimes the model may change asynchronously (the data might come it from outside the program). The idea with reflection is that instead of copying data, I can simply pass the model and have whatever needs it use that data, but I'm not sure if thats a good idea or not in terms of design.

Comment: Even if the data can change from the outside, you still need some kind of synchronization. And did you try thinking about using immutable data structures? Maybe with some kind of "change" model?

Comment: @Euphoric: exactly what I was thinking about when I read the question.

Comment: Euphoric is right. It seems that I haven't thought that hard about synchronization yet. Maybe it's because I'm worried about performance (which is wrong)

Comment: _Can_ it be part of design? Yes. _Should_ it be? That's contextual, and unless a _sufficient_ valid justification exists, you should err towards not doing so. Should _you_ do it in this case? No, this sounds like you're trying to use reflection just to avoid having to do OOP's proper object management. The reason I'm commenting this is to point out that you need to be very careful about asking for a general truth when your specific case may deviate from the general scenario, and you're going to get wrong answers when you don't account for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without an example, this question is a little bit too broad for my taste, so best answer I can give you is a very generic one. IMHO what you need is a more functional approach:

- model your data using [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). For immutable objects, there is no need to create any copies, they can be passed by reference without the risk of creating any side effects.
- using only immutable data structures forces you to organize your program in a way where each function which could deliver potentially out-of-date results is called "on the fly" at the point in time when the data is needed, not earlier.
- instead of solving problems imperatively by "calculating some data x and y, store it somewhere, reuse parts of it later to calculate a, b, and c", learn how to model problems in a functional way (write functions for calculating a, b, and c based on the functions for calculating x and y).
- model your data flow, maybe graphically - make sure you know exactly which components in your system get data from which other components, and where the "asynchronous changes" are introduced. I recommend [Flow Design](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126122649/http://geekswithblogs.net/theArchitectsNapkin/archive/2011/03/19/flow-design-cheat-sheet-ndash-part-i-notation.aspx) for this.
- reflection is most probably the wrong choice for your problem (not for performance reasons, but for actually introducing more problems than it will solve for you)

EDIT: a really good example of a physical model which seems similar to your problem is the [digital circuit simulator](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html#%_sec_3.3.4) in "Structure and Interpretation of Computer programs". And this example is indeed based on mutable data (though its also using functional elements). Maybe this approach maybe a blueprint for yours.

Comment: +1 for discouraging imperative programming and reflection. In my opinion the only time reflection is appropriate is when  you're trying to inspect unknown objects at runtime and run some generic logic based on its structure. I.e. An IDE.

Comment: I don't think immutable objects are that suitable for my application. Perhaps it's because of the way I designed it so far (it's similar to how a typical game is designed, with game objects having their own state and an update loop that updates their state x times a second). But a more functional approach is certainly something that would be useful for the mathematical/physics stuff.

Comment: @9a3eedi: see my edit

Comment: Although the example seems somewhat simple (everything can be expressed in terms of primitives) compared to my model (each component is unique in terms of what it does and what type data it generates), perhaps this just means I have to simplify my model to baby steps so that I can do something like this. I will now give my design a good rethinking. Thanks.